# How can i set two marginBottom for one component in react native

Tags: react-native, animation, margin

I am going to run an animation via animated.sequence, There is two marginBottom with different values in this animation (for one component), but react native ignore second marginBottom and always run first marginBottom.
How can i set two marginBottom with diffrent values for one component?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Could you post your code, please? It'll help to understand what you're doing

Comment: This the main code:

```